# Given a Force $F$ in newtons, what are the appropriate units for a scalar $Q$ so that $F = Q \times 2.00\rm \:N = 20.0\:N$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, dimensional-analysis

> If:
>   $$ \mathrm{force} = Q \times 2.00\rm \:N = 20.0\:N$$
>   then what does $Q$ equal?

What are the appropriate units for $Q$ so the value of the force comes out with the correct units of newtons?

Comment: Is there some reason $Q=10$ doesn't work?  Can you explain your why or why not?

Comment: Q = 10 does work, but what are the units of Q? 10 of what? Newtons? Kilograms? meters/s^2? Is there a unit for the value of Q?

Comment: Alternatively, is Q unit-less?

Comment: Think through it for yourself.  If $Q=10\,\mathrm{N}$, then what units does $Q \times 2.00\,\mathrm{N}$ have?  How about $Q=10\,\mathrm{kg}$ or $Q=10\,\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}^2$?  What if $Q$ is [dimensionless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionless_quantity)?  We can't do your thinking for you.  I assume you're learning about [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis).  What have you learned so far?

Comment: I was using those units for question clarification, as you requested. They are not possible solutions. This was a question put forth on a physics assignment dealing with forces and accelerations.

Comment: My point is that you should think about the consequences of any one of those choices.  That would help you understand the answer for yourself.  As it is, it looks like you have made no attempt to think about this at all.  This is not a question-and-answer site.  Read the [homework policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange/715#715) for guidance on  how to ask good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not the way you posted it but, a Force is a vector quantity.
So $10 * \vec 20.0 N$ is a valid "scalar - vector multiplication". So it's totally valid for $Q = 10$, as a scalar, dimentionless.